# Stored Procedure Update If Exists and greater than the existing value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to Update table `TblNames` if the name = `@name` exists update the columns comparing with existing row data.

**Table (TblNames)**

```
id | name  | val1 | val2 | val3 
1  | name1 |  10  |  12  |  13
2  | name2 |  11  |  13  |  15
3  | name3 |  15  |  12  |  11
4  | name4 |  10  |  12  |  13
```

**parameters** `@name, @val1, @val2, @val3`

If `name` exists select row and

compare `val1` with `@val1` parameter

```
if val1 < @val1 
then @val1 = val1
else val1 = @val1
```

compare `val2` with `@val2` parameter

```
if val2 > @val2 
then @val2 = val2
else val2 = @val2
```

Average of `val3` and `@val3` parameter

```
( val3 + @val3 ) / 2
```

Finally

```
Update TblNames set val1 = @val1, val2 = @val2, val3 = @val3 Where name = @name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
UPDATE TblNames 
SET val1 = IIF(val1 < @val1, @val1, val1),
    val2 = IIF(val2 > @val2, @val2, val2), 
    val3 = (val3 + @val3) / 2
OUTPUT inserted.Val1, inserted.Val2, inserted.Val3
WHERE name = @name
```

Comment: @shadow You can use the output clause. Edited my answer to include that.

Comment: Thanks  @Zohar It's clean and simple

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` expressions for `val1` and `val2` and just the arithmetic expression for `val3`.

```
UPDATE tblnames
       SET val1 = CASE
                    WHEN val1 >= @val1 THEN
                      @val1
                    ELSE
                      val1
                  END,
           val2 = CASE
                    WHEN val2 <= @val2 THEN
                      @val2
                    ELSE
                      val2
                  END,
           val3 = (val3 + @val3) / 2
       WHERE name = @name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query to create procedure for your problem...

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Name_Calculation_value (
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20) = NULL
    ,@val1 INT = NULL
    ,@val2 INT = NULL
    ,@val3 INT = NULL
    )

BEGIN
    AS

    IF EXIST(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TblNames) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.TblNames
        SET val1 = CASE 
                WHEN val1 < @val1
                    THEN @val1
                ELSE val1
                END
            ,val2 = CASE 
                WHEN val2 <= @val2
                    THEN @val2
                ELSE val2
                END
            ,val3 = (val3 + @val3) / 2
        WHERE name = @name;
    END
```